# Migration:refresh is throwing an error when trying to add a foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I am trying to add a foreign key to one table, but when I add the foreign key, and then try to run `php artisan migrate:refresh`, I keep getting thrown the below error.

```
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'properties' already exists (SQL: create table `properties` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null, `property_title` varchar(255) not null, `property_description` varchar(255) not null, `property_image` varchar(255) not null, `user_id` bigint unsigned not null, `id` bigint unsigned not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

properties migration schema:

```
Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('property_title');
            $table->string('property_description');
            $table->string('property_image');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreignId('id')->constrained('users');
        });
```

users migration schema:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: does your migration have a `down` method that removes the `properties` table? if so, are there other migrations that are trying to create this table? you can search your project for `Schema::create('properties'` to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $table->foreignId('x') creates a column, so having the bigInteger and foreign id lines is redundant and will cause errors.

**Remove:**

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
```

Then the foreign ID should be the name of the foreign column. So 'id' should be changed to 'user_id'. So you can change the last line to this:

**Change**

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
```

You could also get rid of the 'constrained('users') at the end and replace is with a 'foreignIdFor' and laravel will figure out which table it belongs to based on the columns name:

```
$table->foreignIdFor(User::class);
```

[Here is the docs link describing this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

**Down function**

Lastly, migrate:refesh won't work if you don't have a down() function in the migration file. So make sure you include a down function like so:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('properties');
}
```

This should be in the same file as your 'up()' function for the properties table

Comment: `You could also get rid of the 'constrained('users') at the end and laravel will figure out which table it belongs to based on the columns name` I don't think this statement is right... if you could perhaps highlight this from the documentation?

Comment: I've changed it to foreignIdFor to account for this